# XML Parser Xcode really slow

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode, parsing, performance

I'm developing an iPhone application and have some trouble with my xml parser. I have to check multiple values from multiple XML files, but when the XML parser is active I can't do anything else. This is not how I want it, because checking the xml must be done in the background, without being noticed. Here is some of my code, hope it's enough!

```
appDelegate.datavalues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i = 0; i < [headarray count]; i++){
    NSMutableArray *infoarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[headarray objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSString *IP = [infoarray objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString *Unique = [infoarray objectAtIndex:2];
    NSString *Port = [infoarray objectAtIndex:3];
    NSString *relay = (NSString *)[infoarray objectAtIndex:4];
    NSString *input = (NSString *)[infoarray objectAtIndex:5];
    NSLog(@"relay%@",relay);
    NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@:%@/state.xml",IP,Port];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSString *authHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@",Unique];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval: 3];
    [request setValue:authHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    //NSURLConnection *connectionResponse = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    NSURLResponse *myURLResponse;
    NSError *myError;

    NSData* myDataResult = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse:&myURLResponse error:&myError];


    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:myDataResult];
    XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];
    //parser.relay = [infoarray objectAtIndex:4];
    //Set delegate
    [xmlParser setDelegate:parser];
    //Start parsing the XML file.
    BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];
```

after this I check some values so I don't think that's necessary to show!

Answer (score 1):

You could refactor the XML-related code into a separate method and then you can use Grand Central Dispatch to run the method in background:

```
- (void) startOperation
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0), ^{
        [self runSomeXMLChecks];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // This is dispatched on the main queue so that
            // you can update the UI. The NSLog is just an example.
            NSLog(@"XML check done!");
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the NSOperation and NSOperationQueue APIs and/or the Concurrency Programming Guide. (Both are in the Xcode library).

From the docs:

> The NSOperationQueue class regulates the execution of a set of
>   NSOperation objects. After being added to a queue, an operation
>   remains in that queue until it is explicitly canceled or finishes
>   executing its task. Operations within the queue (but not yet
>   executing) are themselves organized according to priority levels and
>   inter-operation object dependencies and are executed accordingly. An
>   application may create multiple operation queues and submit operations
>   to any of them.

Comment: and do you know what is the best way to cancel it??

Comment: Set a flag when you want to cancel it.  Have your `XMLParser` check the flag and, if it's set, execute `[xmlParser abortParsing]`.